# Original file content of /boot/cmdline.txt in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

anyone have the original file content of /boot/cmdline.txt. I accidentally edited the file for k3s but the raspberry pi won't boot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how this varies per device and OS, but here's mine. It's off a Pi 4 Model B, on the latest OS version with kernel version. 5.10

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=dd2cc413-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

The value of `PARTUUID` will be different on your device.

Comment: root partitionid will be different per device for sure at far as i know